# Best practice: getting Angularjs component's bindings inside controller

Tags: angularjs, binding, components

I'm converting an app from 1.4 to 1.6.6.
I need to use the bindings in the controller, passing an element in one way binding
I'm trying to access the value passed in the controller using $onInit but it doesn't work (this.value undefined while string values are already there).
I've solved the issue using
1)OnInit and timeout  OR
2) OnChange.
Is it correct? There is something I'm missing? Wasn't it supposed to be all bound inside onInit? There is written that in certain circumstances the value are not available...documentation is vague I think...why is that? Are there any other more elegant solutions?

My html:

```
<gravatar value="$ctrl.contact.email" size="50" class="img-circle"></gravatar>
```

My component:

```
angular
  .module('app')
  .component('gravatar', {
    template: '<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{ $ctrl.value | gravatar }}?s={{$ctrl.size || 64}}" class="{{$ctrl.class}}">',
    controller: Gravatar,
    bindings: {
      value: '<',
      size: '@',
      class: '@'
    }
  });
```

My Controller version 1 and 2:

```
this.$onInit = function () {
    var size = (this.size) ? this.size : 64;
    $timeout(function () {
      this.log.log($scope.$ctrl.contact);
    }, 0);

  };


 this.$onChanges = function (changesObj) {
    this.log.log(changesObj.value);
    if (changesObj.value.currentValue) {
      this.img = 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/' + this.md5(this.value) + '?s=' + this.size;
    }
  };
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking? It's a bit unclear. What is what, and what is it that isn't working?

Comment: Right, elaborating...